# Get hyperlink click event of MS office applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have a strange requirement from my client. They want to have some hyperlinks witin the documents of any MS office applications like MS word, excel, powerpoint etc. If any sentence is hyperlinked with some value, can i get an event of that hyperlink in my asp.net C# code.? I have stuided `INTEROP` dll of .net. I know that a new excel workbook can be created or a word document can be created but can i get an event of the hyperlink that lies within the document.?

please help

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you could do here.

1. You could make all the hyperlinks point to a specific web page that does what you need to do.
2. Or, you could register your own protocol.  Instead of `http` you could register `myProtocol` protocol and make all the links in the docs `myProtocol://my.custom.protocol`.  Having your application registered to handle that protocol.
3. register as the default web browser.  This would allow you to handle all the links without changing the current documents.

Each has its own problems obviously.  A web page isnt local so it doesnt have all the ability that a local app has, a custom protocol isnt very user friendly, and hijacking the default web browser could make your users upset.

This idea should be rethought, but there are a few options.

Comment: So conclusion is that it is hard to execute but can be done..??

Comment: @user3004443 it depends on your execution.  Can you modify the links in the files?

Comment: Actually I dnt have ti manipulate the links, just read the links and get the click event if the link is clicked.

Comment: let me understand.  you want to capture all the links when the USER clicks?

Comment: Not all the links but just the link which the user has clicked which is present EXCEL,WORD etc.

Comment: unless you can modify the link.. your app has to become the default web browser.